# GCP cloud run custom domains and correct ssl cert?

Tags: gcp, google-cloud-run

I setup a customer domain on GCP cloud run xxx.domain.com but when I go to https://xxx.domain.com, the cert served is the one for the generated url *.a.run.app

for https://xxxxxxxxx-jynhcjgnea-uc.a.run.app

Where I can see the progress on any generated certs for custom domains?  Or is it that when the custom domain progress is finished, the cert is done too?  I ask the second one since it is still not working and I get the typical

NET::ERR_CERT_COMMON_NAME_INVALID and looking at the cert reveals it is for *.a.run.app and not for xxxxx.domain.com

Has anyone succeeded in setting GCP cloud run with custom managed domain up?

Comment: I get the impression from https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/mapping-custom-domains that you need to *"add a global external Application Load Balancer in front of your Cloud Run service and configure a custom domain at the load balancer level."*  Then there is where you can/need to install a TLS certificate for your domain. 
*"One advantage of using a global external Application Load Balancer is that it gives you a lot of control around your custom domain setup. For example, it allows you to use your own TLS certificate"*

Comment: Are you getting an error when you go to **https://xxx.domain.com/**? If not the certificate was correctly generated. A certificate can have multiple CNs. Review the **Subject Alternative Names**.

Answer (score 0):

Based from this [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/mapping-custom-domains?_ga=2.118995082.-247269382.1694444994&_gac=1.195768158.1696375281.CjwKCAjw9-6oBhBaEiwAHv1QvMYpOOqvrgh_byAg5_NzztEpQASR0bnAEeHKQKT5BlY77ntAngK2JhoCyfIQAvD_BwE#limitations) it was mentioned that Google-managed certificate is automatically issued when you map custom domain or renew it.

TLS 1.0 and 1.1 cannot be disabled unless you use Firebase Hosting or Cloud Load Balancing to enable TLS 1.2-only traffic. I suggest performing an SSL checker online to check the status of your SSL certificate. You can use this [link](https://cloud.google.com/load-balancing/docs/https/setting-up-https-serverless#ssl_certificate_resource) as a guidance if you consider using Cloud Load Balancing to handle you SSL certificate.